# Unexpected Identifier error when performing multiple async API Call

Tags: node.js, axios

I have an async function with multiple API calls in it. The first call go through successfully and I get the response, but I get an "**Unexpected Identifier**" error for the second call.

```js
    async function GetList(req, res, callback) {
        var response = await axios.post("http://someURL.com/GetList", req.body);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            response.data.forEach(element => {
                element.forEach(em => {
                    var getChildList = await axios.post("http://someURL.com/GetList2", em);
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but `await` does not pause a `.forEach()` loop.  You could use a regular `for` loop and it would pause it.  What are you trying to return from your function?

Comment: What are you expecting `response.data` to be?   What is it an array of?  Your code seems to assume it's an array of arrays.  Is that what it is?

Comment: @jfriend00, it's an array of arrays.

Comment: What exactly is the "unexpected identifier" and on what line of your code?  Can you give us the entire error message, exactly as it appears?